# Redux doesn't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem with Redux doesn't update the state. Component gets right initial state. Action is dispatched right, data is fetched right and is accesible in action payload inside reducer. Reducer is executing, right case in switch is picked. Just new state doesn't appear in component. I have three others components where it works just fine, only this one cracks.

**component**

```
import fetchLinksPage from '../state/links/actions'
...

let Links = ({linksPageLoaded, linksPage, fetchLinksPage}) => {
  useEffect( () => {
      if(!linksPageLoaded) {
        fetchLinksPage()
        console.log(linksPage)
      }
  },[])

  return ( ... )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({linksPageReducer}) => {
  return linksPageReducer
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchLinksPage: () => dispatch(fetchLinksPage())
  }
}

Links = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Links)
```

**actions**

```
// action types
export const GET_LINKS_PAGE = 'GETLINKSPAGE'
export const LINKS_PAGE_LOADED = 'LINKSPAGELOADED'
export const LINKS_PAGE_ERROR = 'LINKSPAGEERROR'

// action creators
export const getLinksPage = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_LINKS_PAGE
  }
}
export const linksPageLoaded = (data) => {
  return {
    type: LINKS_PAGE_LOADED,
    payload: data
  }
}

export const linksPageError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: LINKS_PAGE_ERROR,
    payload: error
  }
}

const fetchLinksPage = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getLinksPage())
    fetch('http://portfolio.adamzajac.info/_/items/links?fields=*,logo.*.*')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        dispatch(linksPageLoaded(data.data))
      })
      .catch( error => {
        dispatch(linksPageError(error))
      })

  }
}

export default fetchLinksPage
```

**reducer**

```
import * as actions from './actions.js'

const linksPageReducer = (state={}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.GET_LINKS_PAGE:
      return { ...state, linksPageLoading: true }
    case actions.LINKS_PAGE_LOADED:
      //console.log('update state')
      return { ...state, linksPage: action.payload, linksPageLoading: false, linksPageLoaded: true }
    case actions.LINKS_PAGE_ERROR:
      return { ...state, linksPageError: action.payload, linksPageLoading: false}
    default:
      return { ...state, linksPageLoading: false, linksPageLoaded: false, linksPage:[], linksPageError:''}
  }
}

export default linksPageReducer
```

**store**

```
import aboutPageReducer from './state/about/reducer'
import projectsPageReducer from './state/projects/reducer'
import skillsPageReducer from './state/skills/reducer'
import linksPageReducer from './state/links/reducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  aboutPageReducer,
  projectsPageReducer,
  skillsPageReducer,
  linksPageReducer
})

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
)
```

Comment: maybe you can install redux plugin to chrome to debug if you state can be updated properly

Comment: and if it is possible I think you should rename the action creator and the props, it is quite confusing when looking at your code

Comment: State is updating properly in three other components built with the same schema as this one. I know my naming can be little awkward, but its my first react project and i still learning patterns.

Comment: can you put a console.log('render links') inside your Links component to see if it gets called when state updated

Comment: Ok, after installing Redux DevTools i saw state is actually updated. But logging state in useEfect hook always show its initial value, don't really understands why.